# Left-align single elements on Masonry

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-masonry

I'm using the masonry plugin to render some search results on my web application in a stylish way. Although I'm facing a problem illustrated on [this image](http://snag.gy/9XeZP.jpg).

As you can see the pink square positions himself under the white square, which makes sense in order to minimize the vertical space required to display all the squares. But I was asked to left-align the pink square so that it stays under the red one.

This was asked because it feels odd when displaying too few results to have a square lost in the middle of "row" of squares.

Has anybody faced this problem before? Is this solvable without a lot of custom code over masonry?

Comment: Have you tried the option "isOriginLeft"?

Comment: yes, but doesn't work, because the pink square doesn't stay bellow the red    one.

Comment: You need to post some code. An image is not enough. Also, what have you tried so far?